# Map manipulation in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

As I have 4 key/value in map , I'm trying to store two keys in string format and rest two in an array.

right now what output I'm getting :

```
{ url: 'account/43',    
  status: '200',    
  headers: '\'content-type\' = \'application/json\'',    
  body: '{ name: Fatma Zaman }' }
```

Expected output:

```
{ url: 'account/43',    
  status: '200',    
  headers: [ '\'content-type\' = \'application/json\'' ],    
  body: [ '{ "name": "Fatma Zaman" }' ]}
```

below are the code which is returning all key/value pair in string, I can make all key/value pair in array but not sure how to do only two key's value to array.

```
function processFile(content) {

  lodash.forEach(content, function(node) {

    if (node.startsWith("//")) {

      key = node.substring(2, node.length - 2).toLowerCase().trim()
      return

    } else {
      value = node
    }

    map[key] = value
  })

  console.log(lodash.map(map, "key"))
  return map

}
```

Comment: And what's the input on `processFile` that gives you problems?

Comment: content = [ '//     URL//',

  '/account/42',

  '//Status//',

  '200',

  '//HEADERS//',

  'content-type = application/json',

  '//BODY//',

  '{ name: Fatma Zaman }',

  '//HEADERS//',

  'content-type = application/text' ]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple condition based on key name and put the value in array

> map[key] = ['header', 'body'].includes(key) ? [value] : value;

```
function processFile(content) {
  lodash.forEach(content, function(node) {
    if (node.startsWith('//')) {
      key = node
        .substring(2, node.length - 2)
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim();
      return;
    } else {
      value = node;
    }

    map[key] = ['header', 'body'].includes(key) ? [value] : value;
  });
  return map;
}
```

Comment: This solution solve my purpose and another problem is I have multiple value of header. below are the expected output
`{ url: 'account/43' 

  status: '200' 

  headers:

   [ 'content-type = application/json',

     'content-type = application/text' ],

  body: [ '{ name: Fatma Zaman }' ] }`

Comment: if I add below code , it's giving me multiple value but not url/body not in string 
  `if (key in map) {

            map[key].push(value)

        } else {

            map[key]= [value]

        }`

Comment: In short , I'm not able to achieve both at the same time. like multiple header value with url/status in string format. @Zahaib Ijaz , Any suggestion and help would be appreciable.